# Mongodb replication seems to be abnormal- Primary contains less data as compare to secondaries

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a three member replica set as 1 primary and 2 secondaries 
A - Primary
B - Secondary
C - Secondary

Initially I had only one Member A and all CRUD operations were performed  on this only.

After some time I have introduced 2 secondaries B and C. For some reason, secondaries were removed and rejoined in cluster.

When I have stepdown node A to make node C primary, it seems to be abnormal:

Node A

```
rs1:SECONDARY> show dbs
TEST  2136.457GB
```

Node B

```
rs1:PRIMARY> show dbs
TEST  351.329GB
```

Node C

```
rs1:SECONDARY> show dbs
TEST  2136.457GB
```

The new primary node has less data. Was it because it became stale at any point of time? How should I be able to know it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, now for the bad news. You are on the wrong site. Questions about database administration and configuration can be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. StackOverflow is for "programming" based questions, which this is not. Please post on the correct site instead of here.

Comment: Thank you Blakes for the update..